# Error in Faraday and RubyGems API

Tags: rubygems, faraday

I want to obtain the list of gems of an owner. My HTTP client is Faraday, I'm doing something like this:

```
connection = Faraday.new "https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems.json"
connection.token_auth(token)
response = connection.get
```

But I have the error

```
"@body="Access Denied. Please sign up for an account at http://rubygems.org""
```

I don't know if I am authenticating in a wrong way or is with another method. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just fyi I solved it with a header

```
    connection = Faraday.new 
    response = connection.get 'https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems.json', {},{'Authorization' => token}
```